# Changing Header Logo

Tags: magento-1.8

I am new to using Magento other than basic data entry but I cannot figure out how to change the header logo on my current magento skin.  I even tried to do it on the cpanel with no success...how do I change it?

Answer (score 3):

For changing logo goto

```
skin/frontend/Your_theme/images
```

upload your logo image in images folder of your theme

Now in admin section goto

```
System->Configuration->General-Design->Header and in Logo Image Src
```

give your image name.

```
images/Your_imagename.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the call for the logo img source in your themes header.phtml file.  In this file you will find:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrcSmall() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="small" />
```

The getLogoSrc() function is looking for a value in system/configuration/design/header/logo_src.  In this config you can define the path to your logo relative to your skin directory.

```
skin/frontend/[package]/[your_theme]/[path]/[to]/logo.jpg
```